# Image can not be displayed after upload using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have an issue. I can not display image after selecting using `ng-file-upload` from Angular.js. I have to upload multiple file here. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Image{{$index+1}}:</span>
      <div>

        <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}" ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" custom-on-change="uploadFile" ngf-select="onFileSelect($index,$file);">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

      </div>
      <span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="mulImage.length>0">
      <img ng-src="{{attchImage}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);">
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(event) {
    console.log('event', $scope.mulImage.length);
    var files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };
  $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.attchImage = e.target.result;
    });
  }
```

Here i need after selecting the image it should display inside image tag but failed to do that. [Here is my plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/X2l6NIVsN2hak8TQjupV?p=preview) code. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This one look very friendly :)

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: yes,i am also using that but unable to display the image.

Comment: Here is the working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/W0Js9DEj07Eq5qxiFQz8?p=preview use `ngf-src`

Answer (score -1):

You used 'onFileSelect' in your view and defined $scope.onFileSelect1. 
If I edit it the plunkersample runs for me. 
Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: my problem was i could not able to preview the image.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood something. 
Where do you want to preview it? I thought you want to display the uploaded image to the left of the green plus button. And as you can see, this worked for me. Just the picture wasn't ever uploaded.